# How to use the variables defined in the flyway.conf file within it

Tags: flyway

I have a scenario for defining two parameters in a flyway.conf file with the following structure:

flyway.placeholders.parameter1: value1
flyway.placeholders.parameter2: $ {parameter1} _ value2

Can I define the parameters this way? Because when I call parameter 2 from the sql file, it does not return a proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, placeholders can't be inserted into other fields in the configuration file.

Using `${ ... }` inside `flyway.conf` will instead try inserting an environment variable. In this case it would be trying to insert an environment variable called `parameter1`, so if this doesn't exist it just inserts an empty string.

`parameter2` might have to be defined manually instead, or you could assign both `parameter1` and `parameter2` using an environment variable.